# How to do slider like this? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

On this site https://pintastic.com/, exist slider, with images and text changes. How to do, or copy this slider? Or which plugin can help me, to do this simple?

Comment: look at the source code for clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using jCarouselLite

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php

[Link to the documentation](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/documentation.php)